# DDEV: Can't Access Site Via Hostname, hosts File Not Updated

Tags: ddev

I created a new DDEV project in an empty directory with `ddev config`. Then I used `ddev start`, and confirmed the project was running with `ddev describe`. So far so good.

When I access the project via `http://127.0.0.1:[port number]` in the browser it resolves fine. But when I try to access it via `http://my-project-name.ddev.site`, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error in Chrome.

I checked out the [troubleshooting guide in the FAQ](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#ddev-starts-but-browser-cant-access-url) and went down the list:

> If you’re not connected to the internet, your browser will not be able to look up *.ddev.site hostnames.

I'm connected to the internet.

> DDEV assumes that hostnames can be resolved within 3 seconds. That assumption is not valid on all networks or computers, so you can increase the amount of time it waits for resolution.

Increased to 5 seconds as per the recommendation. Still no.

> If DDEV detects that it can’t look up one of the hostnames assigned to your project for that or other reasons, it will try to add that to the hosts file on your computer, which requires administrative privileges (sudo or Windows UAC).

DDEV didn't ask me for admin privileges at any point, so I have no idea if it tried to write to the hosts file. If I open my hosts file I don't see any new entries beyond the base localhost settings.

One final note in case it's relevant: when I run `ddev start` I get an error message

> Failed to start [my-project]: unable to listen on required ports, port 443 is already in use

However I've confirmed nothing else is using port 443 except Docker, and when I access the site via `https://127.0.0.1:[port number]` the site also resolves fine. So maybe it's related or maybe it's an unrelated bug.

**System Info:**

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Docker 4.15.0
- DDEV 1.22.3
- No other servers or virtual machines installed

Comment: Thanks for checking the troubleshooting guide! Could you please see if you can `ping xxx.ddev.site` successfully? If you can't you probably can't look up `*.ddev.site` so your DNS isn't working right, probably DNS Rebinding problelm, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#ddev-starts-but-browser-cant-access-url

Comment: @rfay Thanks for the quick response! I have good news and bad news: the good news is that yes, my DNS needed to be updated (I just re-installed my OS so my router settings got wiped); the bad news is that while I can now successfully ping the site URL, it still won't load in the browser :/

Comment: Progress! It would be easier to help you with something like this in Discord, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k - But please do `ddev debug test` and share the output as a gist on gist.github.com, we'll see what it says.

Comment: So for whatever reason fully restarting the computer fixed the problem (classic!). It must have killed whatever mysterious process was blocking DDEV from fully starting, the 443 error is gone and I can access the project from the ddev.site URL now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the entire computer seems to have fixed the issue, I guess it must have killed whatever mysterious process was interfering with DDEV doing a full startup. The port 443 error is gone and I can successfully access my project from the `*.ddev.site` url.